# ssh ConnectTimeout invalid option

Tags: ssh, command-line, remote-access

When trying to test the connection to a remote machine I use

`ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $remote_host date`

However when I run the command I get `Invalid option: 'ConnectTimeout=2'`

When I run `ssh --version` I get

`ssh.exe: Reflection for Secure IT 7.2.1.99 on x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit).`

Is ConnectionTimeout only available in newer ssh versions (if so, which?) or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: "Reflection for Secure IT" You're not using the OpenSSH ssh client that most people use. You're using a commercial ssh client from Microfocus. You should refer to the Microfocus documentation, or contact that company for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [kenster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879927/ssh-connecttimeout-invalid-option?noredirect=1#comment74795829_43879927) pointed out, this is not OpenSSH. For Micro Focus's enterprise SSH, the option is `ConnectionTimeout`